# blank records in php-my-admin when submitting data via explorer

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, internet-explorer

I already tried to ask this question with no help....
I have a simple php filethat sends get to another file and this file sends the data to db.
my problem is that all the data that is written in Hebrew is blank. 
need your real help....

my main.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
<head>
<script src="kill.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form>
<input type="text" id="bill" />
<input type="button" value="btn" id="btn" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert('ready');
$("#btn").click(function(){
    chat($("#bill").val());
    });
    var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= handleServerResponse;
 function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
 var xmlHttp;
 if(window.ActiveXObject){
   try{
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false;
       }
}else{
   try{
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch(e){
      xmlHttp = false;
   }
 }
 if(!xmlHttp){
    alert("cant create object");
 }else{

     return xmlHttp;}
 }

 function chat(input){

       if(xmlHttp.readyState==4||xmlHttp.readyState==0){        
           xmlHttp.open("GET","db.php?input="+input , true);
           xmlHttp.send(null);
       }else{
            setTimeout('chat('+input+')',1000);   
       }
   }

 });
```

my db.php (the file that recives the get):

```
<?php
require('connect.inc.php');
header('Content-Type: text/html charset="utf-8"');
session_start();
$input=0;
if(isset($_GET['input'])){
   $_SESSION['input']=$_GET['input'];

}
 $input=$_SESSION['input'];
 $inser_name="INSERT INTO explorer(name) VALUES('$input')";
 $query_run= mysql_query($inser_name);

 echo  $input;

 ?>
```

my connect file:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/html;  charset="utf-8" ');
 $host='localhost';
 $user='root';
 $password='';
  $mysql_db = 'chetty';
 if(@!mysql_connect($host, $user, $password)||@!mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
        die('NO connected');
   }
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",mysql_connect($host, $user, $password));
 ?>
```

my table in the database is encoded properly (utf8_general_ci) 
note that in English everything works fine and more strange is that in chrome its working fine as well (including Hebrew)

Comment: You're using jquery. WHY are you building your own ajax requests? And your code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And why are you connecting to the DB twice? You only have to call mysql_connect ONCE.

Comment: Because i try to set names utf8 and sql injections doesn't concern me at this moment  this code is example that I built to illustrate my problem and it is part of a bigger code.. I know it looks kinda strange...